# How can I get *ngIf to show the div when a certain string is present

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

Still trying to grasp Angular. How can I use the *ngIf directive to only display to following div when a certain string is present. To be more specific, I want the div to show when the phrase 'Que' is present in the 'reason' database column which is part of the database table TutorRequests.

I have tried to use the indexOf() method but I am assuming it is not correctly implemented.

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
 <div class="panel panel-default pre-scrollable pre-scrollable-3">
   <div class ="row">
     <h2>Tutor Request</h2>
       <div *ngIf="tutorRequests.reason.indexOf('Que')">
         <div *ngFor="let tutorRequest of tutorRequests;" style="margin 
                 bottom: 10px;">
          <h5>{{tutorRequest.tutor.firstName + " " + 
             tutorRequest.tutor.lastName}}</h5>
                <p>{{tutorRequest.request.reason}}</p>
           <button style="margin-top: 1px;" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"                       
             (click)="rejectTutorRequest(tutorRequest.tutor.userID)">Unflag
           </button>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
          <div *ngIf="!tutorRequests|| tutorRequests.length == 0">Tutor 
                    Requests to show</div>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
```

I am sure this is a simple fix, but again I am new to angular.

Comment: indexOf return -1 if not exists, but 0 if "Que" is at the start of reason

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method to check if a string contains a substring.

```html
<div *ngIf="tutorRequests.reason.includes('Que')">
```

Answer (score 1):

- ES2016 Specifications included the `includes()` method for Array data structure.
- The `includes()` method check if an array includes a certain element, returning `true` or `false` as appropriate.
- The includes method finds `NaN` and `undefined` whereas the `indexOf` method doesn't.

So thats why you can use following code

```
*ngIf="tutorRequests.reason.includes('Que')"
```

Answer (score -1):

Since `>` is a special HTML character, you need to use an HTML entity.

`<div *ngIf="tutorRequests.reason.indexOf('Que') &gt;= 0">`

Of course, if you only need to know if the string starts with "Que", then this will do:

`<div *ngIf="tutorRequests.reason.indexOf('Que') === 0">`

Comment: Many thanks for your quick suggestion. Yes I do only have to know if it starts with 'Que'. I will give it a go!

Comment: could just do `!tutorRequests.reason.indexOf('Que')` in this case